# Order by summing multiple values

Tags: wp-query, query, mysql, order, sql

In a custom post type (products) I want to order products by summing multiple values based on user selection. I use custom taxonomies to filter the products.

I could use the orderby `meta_value` but the combinations a user could make are so many that it's not possible to store all these totals as post meta.

I think I will need to alter the wp query using filters like `posts_clauses`. Could a custom SQL query handle this effective (or maybe a different approach)?

It's a custom setup so I don't mind how the values are stored. Could be as post meta, in a custom table or even as a json/string in the `post_content` field (I don't make use of it).

Comment: How many different parameters could be used for that sum?

Comment: The user will be able to filter up to 10-15 taxonomies. The sum will be between those but each taxonomy term will be considered as a different value. Every taxonomy will have 10-50 or more terms.

Comment: I don't see enough here to propose an answer. For instance, how are the "multiple values" being turned into criteria for sorting the products, and how many products are there all together? Even if your code doesn't work, an example of what you've tried - or even the logic of it laid out schematically - might be very helpful: It's quite possible, for example, that part of the solution will involve capturing the results of one more or less complex query, and the rest from sorting through them.

Comment: @CKMacLeod I will use the `pre_get_posts` with URL parameters to filter the products. Products could be 1000 or 10.000+. Each filter (taxonomy) will correspond to a different value/price for each product. Simple I am looking for an approach to order by the total of multiple prices.

Comment: I'm  still not understanding either why you've settled on this particular approach or, more important, what precisely you're trying to accomplish. Personally, I'd like to see a fully formed explanation of the problem in your post, not in comments, including whatever code is already written or drafted. But it's up to you how you go about finding a solution. Good luck!

Comment: How are you assigning values to taxonomies? How many taxonomies are there that have such values/points? Is the list of these taxonomies constant (more less)?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I haven't make any assignment yet. If there is an easy way to SUM values/prices using an SQL query I could have values/prices as post meta and taxonomy as key. The user will be able to filter up to 10-15 taxonomies and these will be constant.

Comment: @Christopher OK, so there will always be constant amount of these properties? If so, then I have an idea for efficient solution, but I'll be able to answer tomorrow...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż yes it's a custom project and there will be a constant amount of taxonomies. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use taxonomies or custom fields for this purpose. Every time you're add one custom field for a query, you have to add a JOIN part for that query - it means that with 10-15 custom fields, you'll get query with 10-15 joins - so such query will be very slow.

But there is some nice trick you can use in such case. I would approach it this way:

1. Create custom DB table with a column for every property that can be included in sum. (So there should be one external key `post_id` which will allow you to join this table with posts table and then one column for every property - so `basic_cost`, `extra_cost`, `extra_cost_2` and so on - or whatever your properties are...) This way you'll be able to use these columns in a sum and the query will need only one join.
2. Use [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook to fill that table with meta values.
3. Use [`posts_clauses`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses) hook to join your custom table and order by whatever sum you want based on fields in that table.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the table structure?

Comment: As I have answered you above I have 10-15 taxonomies and each taxonomy will have 10-50 terms. Each term will be considered as a different price/property. So there will be cases that a product will have 500+ prices/properties.

Comment: So? Table containing 500 columns isn't a problem. On the other hand query with 500 joins will be a huge problem...